# Using selenium in python to search email adresses and return information fails when no result

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Using selenium in python to create a script that goes through a list of email, pasts them in the search bar of a webpage and returns personal information as defined into csv file.

Everything is working, but as soon as one email does not give any search results my script stops. I tried using a try, except. But it is not working.

Edit: The page in my script is a placeholder as the page im scraping is company related/Internal.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import os

f = open('email_list.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
email_list = []

for row in csv_f:
   email_list.append(row[0])
f.close()


url = 'https://placeholderpage.com'

webdriver_path = os.path.abspath('./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=webdriver_path)

f = open("DT_Output.csv", "w")

headers = "Name ; Department ; Company ; Address ; Phone ; Mobile ; Email ; Line Manager ; Manager Status ; Status ; OZT\n"

f.write(headers)

for emails in email_list:
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(2000)
        driver.get(url)
        python_button = driver.find_element_by_id('search').send_keys(emails)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('cst-query-btn').click()

        namediv = driver.find_element_by_class_name('vcard-head')
        name = namediv.find_element_by_class_name('name').text

        department = driver.find_element_by_class_name('org-name-alt').text

        company = driver.find_element_by_class_name('company').text

        address = driver.find_element_by_class_name('location').text

        phone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('telephone').text

        mobile = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mobile').text

        email = driver.find_element_by_class_name('email').text

        line_manager = driver.find_element_by_class_name('linemanager').text

        manager_status = driver.find_element_by_class_name('linemanager-status').text

        status = driver.find_element_by_class_name('status').text

        ozt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ozt').text

        f.write(name + ";" + department + ";" + company + ";" + address + ";" + phone + ";" + mobile + ";" + email + ";" + line_manager + ";" + manager_status + ";" + status + ";" + ozt + "\n")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

f.close()
```

Comment: Ah sorry maybe i need to make it more obvious.  The webpage entered is a dummy one, since the one Im scraping is company related/internal. To be clear, the script is working as intended as long all the emails in my list can actually be found in  the webpage. If one email does not lead to a result, it just stops.

Comment: scrapping of website is highly depends on webpage, without knowing it's behaviour how any one suppose to give answer?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I think the issue is that I did not include something that skips to the next email search if the first element: 
namediv = driver.find_element_by_class_name('vcard-head')
        name = namediv.find_element_by_class_name('name').text


does not give a result.

Comment: you should run your program with out exception and check for in which element search it is giving error

Comment: I get the error for the namediv.find_element_by_class_name('name').text element.
Which would make sense because its the first element im trying to find. Since the search does not get any result it already stops at the first element. Thats why I think my try -> except is not even working at all.

Comment: then use try and except before that only, don't cover your entire script with that

Comment: What do you by mean by "the script stops"? Does it crash with an exception? or it just hangs forever?

Comment: I tried doing that, but got the same results. Somehow it is not just going to the next email in my list but just stopping instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help you to put a condition on namediv  object in the code above. Something like below:

if namediv is None :
    print("No Results found for " + emails)
    exit(0)

Better even if you could add a check for any element that appears when there are no results. Believe your code is failing because program is trying to retrieve text from an element that is not present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe the same thing just not sure how to implement it properly. Tried using the try except.. I will try to implement your suggestion, just a question: Does this code snippit continue to loop the next email or does it stop the script entirely?

Comment: This will stop the script entirely; you can use break to skip loop

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution but having it just go to the next email and search if there is no results for one mail. I tried using the 'continue' command but it is not working. It just stays on the webpage, where it says person not found and the script keeps running

Comment: Could you help with the exact error? Would be useful to know at what point there is the error so that we can debug accordingly